# Python - Generate a hierarchical dictionary(tree) from input data

Tags: algorithm

```
Input data = [1,12,122,14] .     
Output data = 
    {
      "1": {
        "children": [
          {
            "12": {
              "children": [
                {
                  "122": {
                    "children": []
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "14": {
              "children": []
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

This seems to have some relation with tries, i am able to generate a trie in python with the input.

Comment: Could you please write what is the question?

Comment: This is sort of like a trie that isn't trying.

Comment: What is your question?  Are you trying to generate a prefix tree? What code have you written?  Is the "Output data" above the data that you are currently getting or the data you want to get?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?  Typically trees and recursive functions work well together.

Comment: Also, `children` should probably not be a list-of-dicts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion, and create a depth limit to determine when to start gathering new nodes into the single list:

```
def trie(d, current = 0, depth = 2):
  if len(d) == len(data):
     return {d[0]:{'children':filter(None, [trie(d[1:]), {d[-1]:{'children':[]}}])}}
  if current == depth:
     return [{i:{'children':[]}} for i in d]
  return {d[0]:{'children':trie(d[1:], current+1)}}

new_data = [[1,12,122,14], [1,12,122,123,14],  [1,14,16,12,122,123]]
new_list = [trie(sorted(i, key=lambda x:str(x))) for i in new_data]
```

Output:

```
[{1: {'children': {12: {'children': [{122: {'children': []}}, {14: {'children': []}}]}}}}, {1: {'children': {12: {'children': [{122: {'children': []}}, {123: {'children': []}}, {14: {'children': []}}]}}}}, {1: {'children': [{12: {'children': {122: {'children': [{123: {'children': []}}, {14: {'children': []}}, {16: {'children': []}}]}}}}, {16: {'children': []}}]}}]
```

Comment: Hi, for input  =[1,12,122,123,14]  the output is https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5a82583b2cc12d126d720010 however the expected o/p is https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5a8258dc9a230212562ace66 @Ajax1234

Comment: given the array first we must sort it lexicographically -> data = [1,14,16,12,122,123]
data = sorted(data, key=lambda x: str(x)) and then proceed to put in hierarchical format. @Ajax1234

Comment: @iajnr please see my recent edit. I created a single list with each of your test lists as elements and called `trie` on each list.

Comment: thanks for the solution but 12 should be parallel to 14 and 16 however 14 and 16 are listed as children of 12..  @Ajax1234

Comment: Also given input=[1,3] output should be https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5a82693f7ecc1012733352e8/1 ... @Ajax1234